# Finalizers in Ruby: is there an equivalent to "__destruct" from PHP?

Tags: ruby, destructor, finalizer

Within PHP classes the parser deals with the `__construct` and `__destruct` methods to instantiate the instance and destroy it when the script exits or you use unset.  When you extend a class you simply use `parent::__construct` and `parent::__destruct` to run any cleanup code that might need running on the class that was extended.

Now within the context of a class that represents DB data and helps you manipulate that data I'd thought that a `__destruct` method could be used to compare current values against the originals grabbed from the DB and do an UPDATE when necessary (in some cases just always do an UPDATE so long as the Primary Key value cannot be changed).  Implementing this in PHP is pretty straight forward.

The main upside to this approach would be to simply manipulate class variables quickly as needed and then have the class do one big UPDATE at the end.  In long scripts that run for minutes it might be nice to create DB instance during __construct, get the data, close the DB connection, and then manipulate class variables only during the minutes long execution.  On __destruct, open up a new DB connection make the UPDATEs and then close down the DB connection and clean up anything else that needs cleaning up.

I'm curious what people's thoughts are on whether or not this is a good idea/bad practice but my main question was is this possible in Ruby.

In Ruby you have the initialize method that runs when you instantiate an instance of the class.  The Ruby equivalent of `parent::__construct` is `super` in Ruby. And there is the `ObjectSpace.define_finalize` and `finalize` method for Ruby classes.  However, as I understand it, the finalize method isn't supposed to be able to reference the instance calling it.  On top of that I can't find any equivalent to `parent::__destruct`. I suspect that's because there isn't an equivalent since it seems that the `finalize` method was explicitly designed to prevent referencing itself.

Anyone out there know of way to do this? If not, what's the best practice for dumping Ruby classes to get back resources and prevent data loss? Does everyone have a garbage_collection method they call just before setting a class instance to nil or is there some other way?

Thanks

Comment: Ruby (MRI), like many languages/runtimes that do not require strict memory management (C++) or that do not use a ref-counting/hybrid approach (PHP GC), does not support a notion of a "destructor" as such .. it's generally best to re-think the solution.

Comment: Goes into a lot of detail on topic: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/17155

Comment: @ficuscr, I'd read that forum post and figured that what I proposed was probably counter to the design decisions of Matz/Ruby maintainers.  I was hoping someone had found a way around it though. So I'm guessing the answer is there is no way in Ruby?

Comment: @pst, I've seen a few StackOverflow posts that suggested that updating a DB in the finalizer would lead to bugs that were difficult to track down.  In my case though the classes are small and rather simple so I think decent code comments can handle bug tracking.  Ultimately this solution seemed like a convenience but I've run into issues of having too many DB connections open and crashing the server - i.e. running hundreds of concurrent instances of a tool kicked off by a cron job.  So the thought of "managing" the number of DB cxns in this way had some appeal.

Comment: @gabe, Think that is the answer.  Make any cleanup explicit and don't look to interact with things under GC.

Comment: @gabe I still do not see why there is a reason to handle anything in the "destruct", much less anything that deal with data .. if you wish data is persisted, tell it to be persisted. e.g. `context.Update(objectGraph)` or `object.Save` are two approaches, depending on preferred pattern. The problem with a destructor in a language like Ruby (in MRI and JRuby implementations) is that *it is not guaranteed*. You *can* add closured or ObjectSpace finalizers (closer over a *separate* data object [e.g. used via composition]) for objects .. but **you will run into trouble**. It is not worth it.

Comment: @pst, If the destructor in Ruby isn't guaranteed then its clearly unacceptable. The point would be to make sure the DB gets updated at the end of the script without having to do so explicitly. (I've had some difficult to track bugs in my code because a method worked fine but I forgot to call it deep within something that did lots of other things. So having it taken care of in the finalizer would be convenient.) All right, so I think the consensus is that this is a bad idea in general and impossible or nearly so in Ruby.  Thanks

Comment: "could be used to compare current values against the originals grabbed from the DB and do an UPDATE when necessary" is a really bad idea. Database changes should always require an explicit action, what would you do it the UPDATE failed?

Comment: @mu, Long story short, all of my code has that scenario built into it already. When I start running dozens or even hundreds of instances concurrently it seems that a small percentage fail - these tools run against servers that aren't as stable as I'd like. I've been able to track down a few bugs in my code the failures are never eliminated entirely.  There only 2 approaches to solve this that I've used - 1) save the data to a text file for later comparison against the DB state, 2) reattempt the process and be robust to its failing due to having already been completed. I generally go with #2.

Comment: You forgot 3) Fix the code to properly interact with the database. Yeah, this sounds like a lot of work but pain and suffering can be a good teacher :)

Comment: @mu, The failures are due (primarily) to the servers/sites I'm running against dying/returning 404 temporarily mid-process and causing a failure. Sometimes I need to restart the entire process.  Sometimes it failed at the end. I could catch the failure and add some logic to determine if it passed or needs to be redone but that is mess all in itself. My DB calls in PHP have always been explicit - this question was about whether or not I could attempt a new approach going forward on these simple DB interface classes.

Answer (score 5):

No, Ruby has no equivalent to PHP `__destruct`, because PHP destroys an object as soon as its reference count reaches zero, but Ruby is slow to destroy objects. Ruby marks and sweeps objects only from time to time. Also, Ruby is conservative when it scans for local variables of C code. Ruby refuses to destroy an object if a C local might point to it.

Ruby has `ObjectSpace.define_finalizer` but it is difficult to use. An object can have more than one finalizer. If the superclass defined a finalizer, you can define another finalizer on the same object. The problem is that `ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer` removes all finalizers from the object. So if the superclass removes its finalizer, it also removes your finalizer.

Ruby runs the finalizer only after destroying the object. The finalizer must not have a reference to the object. If it does, Ruby never destroys the object, and you have a memory leak. The finalizer must not be in a scope where `self` or a local variable refers to the object.

In the next example, I show how to use a finalizer to update a database. This is a bad idea because Ruby is slow to run finalizers.  The database might not get updated for a long time. I call `GC.start` to force a full garbage collection. My computer's Ruby refuses to destroy one of the objects, so one update doesn't happen yet.

```
require 'forwardable'
require 'pstore'

# Create a database of people's ages.
People = PStore.new('people.pstore')
People.transaction do
  People['Alice'] = 20
  People['Bob'] = 30
  People['Carl'] = 40
  People['David'] = 50
  People['Eve'] = 60
end

# Shows people in database.  This can show old values if someone
# forgot to update the database!
def show_people(heading)
  People.transaction(true) do
    puts heading
    %w[Alice Bob Carl David Eve].each do |name|
      puts "  #{name} is #{People[name]} years old."
    end
  end
end

show_people("Before birthdays:")

# This is a person in the database.  You can change his or her age,
# but the database is only updated when you call #update or by this
# object's finalizer.
class Person
  # We need a PersonStruct for the finalizer, because Ruby destroys
  # the Person before calling the finalizer.
  PersonStruct = Struct.new(:name, :age, :oage)
  class PersonStruct
    def update(_)
      s = self
      if s.age != s.oage
        People.transaction { People[s.name] = s.oage = s.age }
      end
    end
  end
  private_constant :PersonStruct

  # Delegate name (r) and age (rw) to the PersonStruct.
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators(:@struct, :name, :age, :age=)

  # Find a person in the database.
  def initialize(name)
    age = People.transaction(true) { People[name] }
    @struct = PersonStruct.new(name, age, age)
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, @struct.method(:update))
  end

  # Update this person in the database.
  def update
    @struct.update(nil)
  end
end

# Now give everyone some birthdays.
Person.new('Alice').age += 2
Person.new('Bob').age += 1
Person.new('Carl').age += 1
Person.new('David').age += 1
Person.new('Eve').age += 2

# I forgot to keep references to the Person objects and call
# Person#update.  Now I try to run the finalizers.
GC.start

# Did the database get updated?
show_people("After birthdays:")
```

My computer gives this output:

```
Before birthdays:
  Alice is 20 years old.
  Bob is 30 years old.
  Carl is 40 years old.
  David is 50 years old.
  Eve is 60 years old.
After birthdays:
  Alice is 22 years old.
  Bob is 31 years old.
  Carl is 41 years old.
  David is 51 years old.
  Eve is 60 years old.
```

I added 2 years to Eve's age, but there was no update before I checked the database. The C code that interprets Ruby might have left a reference to `Person.new('Eve')` in some local variable, so Ruby would not destroy the object. The result might change if you use another version of Ruby or a different C compiler. Ruby does run any leftover finalizers when the program exits, so the update did happen, but it was too late.

Answer (score 4):

as pst noted in his comment you don't need a destructor for ruby. Just set all referring variables to null ( ref = nil ) and the object will get deleted by garbage collection. You can not know exactly when its garbace collected (deleted). In addition you could ( not that I recommend ) write a proc that runs before actuall deletion of that object

```
ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, self.class.method(:finalize).to_proc)
```

Comment: Yeah I've seen this in my Googling but I don't see how I would use it to call the parent class's finalizer.  And from what I've read it can be really tricky and bug prone to do this. I don't know if this is still true in Ruby but here is a post on issues with proc in define_finalizer - http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/02/24/the-trouble-with-ruby-finalizers/

Comment: @pst, I have 2 engineering degrees but neither are in CS and you lost me there. On top of that I only picked up Ruby a few months ago. Do I have this right? The difference is due to the finalizer being a class method not an instance method.  The class persists; the instance does not. The finalizer is a class method not an instance method so the call might have to be explicit regarding the parent class's name - i.e. `{Parent Class Name}.finalize(self)` or something like that as opposed to the generic `parent::__destruct` of PHP. I don't intend to implement this anymore I'm just curious now.

Comment: @gabe My previous statement was confusing. I should have said "Since Ruby does not have destructor methods.. (then it doesn't matter if they are static methods passing in an instance or invoked through other normal invocation of a parent/super-class method)."